# Android Virtual Device loading then not appearing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have recently fixed the 'd:skin' problem in eclipse. I have recently started learning android programming. I want to test an application so i open up the AVD manager create an AVD and i click start it takes about 15 seconds for the bar to get from 0% to 100%. The Loading window closes and no Virtual Device comes up. No error message nothing. I am running a Mac with 4GB RAM.

Comment: It can take a very long time for the AVD to come up.  Also did you check DDMS perspective -- there is an log view there that may have errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state:

> The Loading window closes and no Virtual Device comes up.

It sometimes comes up after a long time. Eventually, it will probably come up. If it still doesn't, take these steps:

- Restart ADB
- Restart IDE
- Restart Computer

Because you stated that the loading window **does** come up, it is probably going to show up. After it does, I'm going to assume it looks something like this:

[image]

So, if you're lucky, this thing will start in 5 - 10 minutes. If you're anything like I was, it will never start, and you'll give up and download GenyMotion instead. GenyMotion emulator will run in about 30 seconds. It is still laggy, but a lot better than the default android one.

Let me know if this helped! :)

Comment: No, not the Android Startup screen.

Comment: It says "Starting emulator for AVD '3.2HVGA' " and then that window disappears and nothing happens.

Comment: @MickyMouse If I helped make sure to accept my answer by pushing the checkmark. **Try to `1) Restart ADB 2) Restart IDE 3)Restart Computer`**

Comment: How do i restart the ADB? (I am like 2 days old to the app development world)

Comment: @MickyMouse First just close and reopen the window with the virtual device...again, I suggest you just use genymotion instead, it's a lot easier. Let me know what happens when closing and reopening the virtual device window. :-)

Comment: @MickyMouse *genymotion not generation